# GitHub: Разрешить push для репозитория

Tags: git, github

Возможно, я что-то не понимаю, но как разрешить изменять свой репозиторий другим пользователям? Разве любой юзер гихаба не сможет скопировать мой репозиторий, внести изменения и сделать `push`? Если нет, то как хотя бы разрешить определенным пользователям изменять... вообщем, ка это все работает? :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Разве любой юзер гихаба не сможет скопировать мой репозиторий

**Может.** Если он публичный, конечно.

> внести изменения

**Может.** Локально. Файлы ж после клонирования у него на диске, он может делать что хочет.

> и сделать `push`

**Не может.** Да и сами подумайте, многие крупные проекты хостятся на гитхабе, как весело было бы, если бы изменения в них мог пушить кто угодно?

Если хотите кому-то разрешить пушить в свой репозиторий, вам нужно добавить его в настройках репозитория в **Collaborators**.

*Но для публичных репозиториев в этом обычно нет необходимости*, т. к. другие могут пушить свои изменения **в собственные копии (форки)** (каждый может создать свой одним нажатием кнопки <kbd>Fork</kbd> наверху), а потом предлагать сам стянуть (pull) изменения из них (pull request).

---

*Есть ещё вопрос лицензий, но это долгая история.*